# How does SNMP agent know which resource to read?

Tags: networking, snmp

I never really understood what happens when a SNMP agent receives a request from the SNMP manager. It reads the requested OIDs in the UDP datagram and then? Does it parse its MIBs files? And how does it knows which is the memory location to get the specific information?

Comment: Then you have to study at least one SNMP agent implementation (such as NET-SNMP agent, open source) to get better understanding. An agent usually does not parse MIB documents, and its internal logic already knows what to query when a request on a specific OID is made.

Comment: So, are you saying that it knows where to find resources at compile-time?

Comment: That really depends on what management objects you are talking about. Most NET-SNMP objects are determined at compile time, as their control logic is compiled into the binaries. However, NET-SNMP also allows itself to be extended at runtime, so you can define how custom objects can be handled. Most can be found in NET-SNMP documentation, but if you look into the code base you can see all details.

Comment: An SNMP Simulator is a special SNMP agent which tries to delay the binding from compile time to run-time, so that you can simulate many scenarios, eg. by assigning scripting to MIB objects.